# Group values from an array inside of an foreach-loop in order to prevent writing the same code over and over

Tags: php, loops, grouping

I'm getting a lot of tags from a database, and I want to put them into sepparate groups in order to do something for each group, then something for each tag.

I decided to use `PDO.fetchAll()` instead of making a new query to the database for each group. Then have `if(in_array())` inside the `foreach()`-loop in order to get the correct data for each group - like this:

```
$qry_tags = $con->query('SELECT id, NO name FROM tags');
$get_tags = $qry_tags->fetchAll();


<!--each group-->
<div class="tags-group">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($get_tags as $tag): if(in_array($tag['id'],array(1,7,18,23))): ?>
        <!--each tag-->
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="<?=$tag['id']?>" class="submit"> 
                <?=$tag['name']?>
                </label>
        </li>
        <!--//-->
        <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--//-->
```

But I was wondering if there could be a way to write only one block of code, and then have some sort of php logic to sepparate each of them? something like a multi level foreach loop.

This "block", as I call it, is kind of a template for each group..

Maybe by using som sort of a third parameter in order to split the tags into sepparate groups?

Comment: Please clarify - you have multiple groups similar to `array(1,7,18,23)`? If so, then probably I'd loop over `$get_tags` after fetching it to reorganize it accordingly, then use a nested `foreach` -the outer for the group, the inner for the `<li>` as you are doing now.

Comment: yeah, like 6 of them. Another would be `array(12,13,22,26)`.

Comment: And how is the group determined? Is it identifiable from some column value? ( it isn't very robust to rely on the `id` in case you delete and re-add any)

Comment: as of right now I don't have anything to identifying each group. That's why I've decided to use `in_array()` and just manually setting the numbers (id).

Comment: Make yourself a 2D array of groups then, and use a nested `foreach`.  Like `$groups = array('g1' => array(1,7,18,23), 'g2'=>array(12,13,22,26))` and wrap your `foreach` with another `foreach ($groups as $g)` using `in_array($tag['id'], $g)`

Comment: It would be much handier if you had a way to identify them in the database though.  You could use a conditional `ORDER BY` like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN id IN (1,7,18,23) THEN 1 WHEN id IN (12,13,22,26) THEN 2...` but it requires hard-coding those values and that's not a great idea.

Comment: If I added an additional field, in my database, as a group handler. Then could it be done in a more simple way then?

Comment: Yes, you could `ORDER BY group_id` then as you loop in the `foreach` whenever the group id changes, you close and reopen `</ul><ul>`

Comment: but when I do `GROUP BY` in my sql I only get one - looks like the last tag in each group - returned. Do you mean I should make a new query on the returned group_id inside my foreach-loop?

Comment: I said `ORDER BY`, not `GROUP BY`, ordering on the new column which identifies the group.

Comment: Yup. You're absolutely correct. My bad. Sorry about that. I got it to work. Thanks for your help..